# How can the origin of SQL in DB2's Dynamic Statement Cache be identified

Tags: sql, dynamic, db2

In an effort to optimize dynamic sql statements sent to DB2, we are saving them to a custome DSN_STATEMENT table.  Each record has PROGRAM_NAME, COLLID and STMT_ID, which in static SQL are enough to identify the actual package.  But how can I identify the program that created the dynamic SQL?

Is this information captured somewhere in DB2, DB2 Connect or some other part of the puzzle?

Edit: I see that Trace 316 collects the transaction name and USER_ID, so that is of some help.  Is there anything else I can do, before I need to go to the SME and ask her where the transaction came from?

Edit 2: We are on mainframe (z/OS).

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and including how you're capturing this information now? I'm sorry, I don't have an answer to your question - but your question has made me curious about the possibility of capturing all queries sent to our DB2 database.

Comment: What system are you on?  I'm assuming an iSeries, because I have a feeling this is pretty much impossible for, say, Java.  Err, getting the 'program', not capturing the statements, which could be done with a monitor.

Comment: If the client app doesn't make those elements available, then DB2 has no way to know what they are. It can't force a remote system to reveal anything past the network adapter. But for some initial background, see [**i Can ... Use Client Special Registers**](http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/i_can/2009/10/i-can-use-client-special-registers.html).